# How to migrate one-to-one relationship to one-to-many relationship in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Currently, I have two custom model classes. Between them previously I set up a one-to-one relationship. But now due to new requirements change, I need to convert the relationship into a one-to-many.

For example, this  is how I previously structure my model classes

```
class Location: Object {
  @objc dynamic private var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var typeString: String = 

}

class Job :Object {
@objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
let location: Location?
}
```

New structure

```
class Job :Object {
@objc dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
let locations = RealmSwift.List<Location>()
}
```

So basically I want to save multiple location objects inside Job class. This new structure is working fine for me. But now I want to migrate old data into this new setup. I try to achieve this using the following code but no success.

```
migration.deleteData(forType: Location.className)
migration.enumerate(ofType:Job.className) { oldObject, newObject in
    let location = migration.create(Location, value: oldObject!["location"]!)
    (newObject!["locations"] as! List<MigrationObject>).append(location)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you have a one to one relationship and you want to now convert that to a one to many relationship (via a List), using the existing location as the first object in the list.

A getcha is you can't have two objects with the same primary key so during the migration process, the old locations have to be removed and will be replaced with a new location with the same properties (and primary key) and then add it to the Job's `locations` List property.

Here's the code:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration( schemaVersion: vers, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
     if (oldSchemaVersion < vers) {
        migration.deleteData(forType: Location.className()) //delete all locations
        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Job.className()) { oldItem, newItem in
           let existingLoc = oldItem!["location"]
           let updatedLoc = migration.create(Location.className(), value: existingLoc)
           let locList = newItem!["locations"] as! List<MigrationObject>
           locList.append(updatedLoc)
        }
     }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting following error when I run your code.

Value of type 'List<MigrationObject>' (aka 'List<DynamicObject>') has no member 'append'

Comment: @user1469015 What version of Realm do you have installed? Also, take a look at the RealmSwift API for [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) - as you can see `.append` is clearly a function of List objects.

Comment: My Realm version 
RxRealm (1.0.0) and.  RealmSwift (~> 3.14).

Comment: this is code worked for me. and migration is working fine. now the app in AppStore 

     migration.deleteData(forType: Location.className()) //delete all locations
     migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Job.className()) { oldItem, newItem in
    let existingLoc = oldItem!["location"]
    let updatedLoc = migration.create(Location.className(), value: existingLoc)
    let locList = newItem?.dynamicList["locations"] 
    locList.append(updatedLoc)

Comment: but  I  began to receive periodic crash messages from crashlytics like this.

"Primary key property 'Location.id' has duplicate values after migration." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Primary key property 'Location.id' has duplicate values after migration

Comment: @user1469015 Correct, which is what I mentioned in my answer *you can't have two objects with the same primary key* . Not sure what this code is doing (from your comment) `.dynamicList["locations` but I would avoid that since it's not officially documented and there are number of bug reports open involving that.

Comment: But if i use your code
 let locList = newItem!["locations"] as! List<MigrationObject>

I am getting this error
 Cannot assign value of type 'MigrationObject' (aka 'DynamicObject') to type 'List<MigrationObject>' (aka 'List<DynamicObject>')

realm version -  Realm 3.21.0

Comment: @user1469015 Wow - that's a 3 year old version of Realm which is probably why you're having issues. You really need to update at this point to 5.x, update your Realm Studio app and your database. A LOT changed between 3.x and 5.x. That code is pulled from a working project so I know it works - but there requirement is a more current Realm version (even 4.x would help). Also, don't forget to delete all Location data because Migration List object cannot append existing objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need the answer or maybe someone else might want the solution.

The main idea is to **retrieve the last created Location object from realm** and append it to the list instead of using the **MigrationObject**.

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Job.className()) { oldItem, newItem in
       let existingLoc = oldItem!["location"]
       let updatedLoc = migration.create(Location.className(), value: existingLoc)
       let savedLoc = updatedLoc.realm?.object(ofType: Location.self, forPrimaryKey: existingLoc.id)
       locList.append(savedLoc)
    }
```

***Please note**: This is my solution and I haven't found any official documentation about it.*